# R: adding to an existing expression()

Tags: r, plot, expression

Assume you have an existing expression() in R, e.g.

```
 myExpression <- expression(x^2)
```

and wish to add <= to it without completely redefining the expression. So I am looking for a command that looks something like

```
myExpression <- bquote(phantom()<=.(myExpression))
```

The above does not work properly, which you can easily verify using

```
plot(1,1, main=myExpression)
```

The result should be

```
expression(phantom()<=x^2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
myExpression <- expression(x^2)
plot(1, 1, main = bquote(phantom()<=.(myExpression[[1]])))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the results as an expression, encapsulate the above in as.expression(). E.g.

    as.expression(bquote(phantom()<=.(myExpression[[1]])))

Comment: This seems completely analogous to the situation in which a beginneR uses `[` to extract a list or datafreme element and fails because they didn't us `[[`. I don't have an R interpreter handy but I think I'm correct in saying that expressions are really lists of language classed elements.